# Why does document.off disable click on button started with document.on but not id.click in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does `document.off` switches off `click` of buttons called using `document.on` but not `$(id).click`?

Following is code in which second button is not working:

```
<button type="button" id="rara">1</button>    
<button type="button" id="baba">2</button>    
<button type="button" id="hadimba">3</button>


$("#hadimba").click(function(e) {
  alert('3')
});

$(document).on('click', '#baba', function(e) {
  alert('2')
});

$(document).off('click').on('click', '#rara', function(e) {
  alert('1')
});
```

[JsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwm2eyor/)

Could anyone please explain this phenomenon? why specific #id.click hit when whole document's event handlers are off?

Comment: Because `$(document).off` only removes those events that were added to `document`. Your first example targets `#hadimba` specifically.

Comment: @Andy: Could you please elaborate a bit in answer. How specifically is hit when document whole is off?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simply scoping.

`$(document)` and `$('#hadimba')` are different objects, and both have their own event handlers. Removing an event handler from one, does not remove it from the other because they are two different objects.

Another way to look at it is that when you attach a click listener on `$(document)`, you are telling `$(document)` what to do when it receives a click event. Likewise, when you add a listener to `$('#hadimba')` you are telling `$('#hadimba')` to do something when it receives a click event.

So when you remove that listener from `$(document)`, it doesn't do anything when it receives the click event. However, this does not stop `$('#hadimba')` from doing something when it receives a click event.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying any handler function for `$(document).off('click')`.
But with immediate chaining with `.on('click',...` you are actually enabling `click` event agin.

Thus your `off()` should be:

```
$(document).off('click','#rara', function(e) {
  alert('1')
});
```

For the second button you need to target `document.body` instead of just `document`.

```js
$("#hadimba").click(function(e) {
  alert('3')
});

$(document.body).on('click', '#baba', function(e) {
  alert('2')
});

$(document).off('click','#rara', function(e) {
  alert('1')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="rara">1</button>    
<button type="button" id="baba">2</button>    
<button type="button" id="hadimba">3</button>
```

Comment: But am i not disabling click event for all documents but enabling for particular ID only by using $(document).off('click').on('click', '#rara', function(e) {???